# Trying to create a Group Selection Box in Google Earth Plugin

Tags: c#, javascript, google-earth-plugin

I am building a c# application that uses the Google Earth plugin through a web browser control. As part of the application, I need to be able to create a multi-select box around a certain area on the globe (think something similar to drag-selecting multiple files in your file browser).

The way I have it set up right now, the c# code keeps track of when I am in select mode, if I am, the first left click pulls the lat-long of that point from the google earth plugin. After that, mouse moves get the lat-long of the opposite corner, and then the c# code calls the following 2 javascript functions:

```
function clearHighlightBox(){
    var placemark = ge.getElementById('DARTselectBox');
    if(placemark)
    {
        ge.getFeatures().removeChild(placemark);
    }
}

function setHighlightBox(lat1, long1, lat2, long2){
    clearHighlightBox();
    var placemark = ge.createPlacemark('DARTselectBox');
    var lineString = ge.createLineString('');
    var coords = lineString.getCoordinates();
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(lat1, long1, 5000);
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(lat1, long2, 5000);
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(lat2, long2, 5000);
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(lat2, long1, 5000);
    coords.pushLatLngAlt(lat1, long1, 5000);
    placemark.setGeometry(lineString);
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
}
```

First off, creating the ID for the placemark this way does not seem to work (ge.createPlacemark('DARTselectBox');). If I switch this to clear everything and remove the ID from the create Placemark call, this at least doesn't crash. However, even when I do that, I only see the right vertical leg of my rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I switch this to clear everything and remove the ID from the
>    create Placemark call, this at least doesn't crash.

The issue is that you can't remove then add an object with the same ID that quickly. In simple terms it is the call to `ge.createPlacemark('DARTselectBox')` that is causing the crash because the ID `DARTselectBox` is still being used internally. You can eventually use it again, but the time is dependent on the WebBrowser control's garbage collection.

To avoid the crash you could try [calling release](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_object.html#a3b5729a874f2a5fb8f3ce7699ac31038) on the placemark so that the ID is freed immediately. See this note on what calling `release` does (*My emphasis*)

> Permanently deletes an object, *allowing its ID to be reused*.
>   Attempting to access the object once it is released will result in an
>   error.

Failing that you could simply toggle the visible state of the placemark, rather than adding and removing it each time.

The actual issue with the ID reuse is listed as a bug and there is some [more information on the problem here](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=253)

**Edit:**

Looking at it looks like there could be a bug with the release method.

If you read the link I posted `code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=253` some of the comments at the bottom seem to suggest this.

Anyhow, a hash would work, so would an incremental counter. But I don't understand why you don't simply set the visibility to false, or else create a Placemark without an ID at all and simply keep a reference to it during the operation.

The display issue is possibly due to tessellation and altitude mode.

Try calling `setTessellate(true)` on the Placemarks geometry object and also make sure the altitude mode is set to `clampToGround` - to do this you call `setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND)` - again on the Placemarks geometry object.

So you have

```
var lineString = ge.createLineString('');
lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt( ... );
lineString.setTessellate(true);
lineString.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND);
```

If that doesn't work, can you try turning the terrain layer off and checking if the lines are there or not?

Also, I have written a free control library that does lots with the API - it is GPL so you can use it pretty much however you like. It does cover lots of things like this.
http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/

Comment: I tried both just releasing the placemark, and removing it as before and then releasing it. Neither of these seemed to work. I think I might just have to change the id to be some kind of hash of the datetime and just store whatever it previously was.

Comment: I did end up just keeping a reference to the placemark. That worked best. So that part is solved, but I am still not sure why the placemark won't display properly.

Comment: Assuming that `ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_TERRAIN, false);` is how to turn off the terrain layer, the lines are missing.

Comment: Very odd, I see you are creating the linestring with coordinates at 5000m what happens if you set this to 0. Don't forget the altitude mode is clamped to the ground. Also, what happens if you set a thicker line width via a style object? Or if you extrude the linestring when the altitude is non 0?

Comment: Also, what are the actual values you are passing in as parameters - lat1, long1, lat2, long2 - are you sure these values are correct?

Comment: OK, so the box issue was me being an idiot. I was accidentally passing in the Top Right and Bottom Right corners of the box instead of the Top Left and Bottom right. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

I have an application that does something very similar. Unfortunately the code is not GPL, so I can't release it here. In general, your approach is correct, but I believe your problem is the structure you are using for building your box.

You either need to use four separate `KmlLineString` objects (one for eatch edge of the box) or a `KmlLinearRing` to create an enclosed box. I don't believe the `KmlLineString` was designed to create a closed polygon, that's what the linear ring is for.

The way you compute your box points looks good to me (comparing it against my working solution), so I'm thinking if you just swap `createLineString` for `createLinearRing` you'll be well on your way.

Google's samples are at the link below. You'll see they use `linearRing` for the enclosed polygon. (About halfway down the page)

https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/geometries

Comment: I should have mentioned this before, but I have tried it using both LineString and LinearRing. The result is the same.